# Trying to reference a value in an object in an array and failing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've spent days trying different techniques to get two X by Z arrays to talk to one-another and have decided to redo it all by making a 2 by X by Z array instead. 0,x,z contains a grid of cubes (prefab Cell) which will store values to be used later for NPC navigation, while 1,x,z contains a grid of tall cuboids (prefab ObstBlock) which are used to detect walls in the scene. If there's a wall, ObstBlock's int Obstructed will become 1. It is this int that I'm trying to reference in the main script.

All Cells and ObstBlocks are generated by an empty object (named "Grid") running GridScript. All Cells run CellScript and all ObstBlocks run ObstBlockScript. Here are my attempts in GridScript:

```
void DetectObstructions(){
    for (int x=0; x<GridSize.x; x++) {
        for (int z=0; z<GridSize.z; z++) {
            Transform cell;
            Transform block;
            cell = Grid [0, x, z];
            block = Grid [1, x, z];
            if (block.GetComponent<ObstBlockScript> ().Obstructed == 1) {
                cell.GetComponent<CellScript>().Weight = 1000;
            }
            else{
                cell.GetComponent<CellScript>().Weight = 500;
            }
            cell.GetComponent<CellScript>().Obstructed = block.GetComponent<ObstBlockScript>().Obstructed;
        }
    }
}
```

I get no errors and this appears when I try to use the Debug tool: This request is not supported by the protocol version implemented by the debuggee.

As requested, the grid creation part of the script:

```
void CreateGrid(){
    Grid = new Transform[2,(int)GridSize.x,(int)GridSize.z];

    for (int x=0; x<GridSize.x; x++) {
        for (int z=0; z<GridSize.z; z++) {
            Transform newBlock;
            newBlock = (Transform)Instantiate (ObstBlockPrefab, new Vector3 (x/4f, 1.0f, z/4f), Quaternion.identity);
            //newBlock.name = string.Format("({0},1,{1})",x,z);
            newBlock.parent = transform;
            newBlock.GetComponent<ObstBlockScript>().Position = new Vector3(x/4f,1.0f,z/4f);
            Transform newCell;
            Grid[1,x,z] = newBlock;
            newCell = (Transform)Instantiate (CellPrefab, new Vector3 (x/4f, -0.125f, z/4f), Quaternion.identity);
            //newCell.name = string.Format("({0},0,{1})",x,z);
            newCell.parent = transform;
            newCell.GetComponent<CellScript>().Position = new Vector3(x/4f,-0.125f,z/4f);
            //if(GameObject.Find("ObstGrid").GetComponent<ObstructionScript> ().ObstGrid[x,z]./*GameObject.*/Find ("ObstBlock").GetComponent<ObstBlockScript>().obstructed == 1){
            //  newCell.GetComponent<CellScript>().Weight = 83;
            //}
            Grid[0,x,z] = newCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't add tags to title and [thank you notes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Is this a `Mono` project?

Comment: Alexei: I see, I'll be sure to remember that in future.
George: I think yes. Not sure what would make it not one... :S

Comment: So what is not working? What do you expect to happen and isn't happening? Also, printing the code that creates the Grid might be useful.

Comment: No value is passed, or it's always 0, even though when the scene is running I can click each block and check that some blocks' Obstructed values are 1 while all cells' Obstructed values say 0. I'll edit the original with the grid creation script.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty straight forward to me. So unless something funky is happening inside CellScript or ObstBlockScript that resets the values, I'd have to guess DetectObstructions() get's executed too early, before any of the ObstBlockScript.Obstructed are set to "1".

This should be easyish to debug using break points or at least by adding Debug.Log to DetectObstructions() to see if any of the ObstBlockScript.Obstructed are 1 at that time the method is called.